# How to disable a view and put gray color to all its pictures and icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, disabled-control

I have a table with rows - includes colorful icons and buttons.
I need to disable the whole table, that mean:

- Disable the buttons.
- Color gray to the whole GUI - also the colorful icons.

I have problems with implementing the second point. I would like to put an element on the whole table, but how can I make the gray color for all my pictures and icons ?

Comment: can you share the code so that we can work with it..?

Comment: did u tried adding/removing css class by jquery when clicked??

Comment: Disable the buttons isn't my problem. I have problem only with the second point.

Answer (score 2):

```
img.grayscale {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
  filter: gray; 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
}
```

append grascale class to your icons and images.

Comment: looks like this requires the browser to support SVG, it's worth being added as a note.

Comment: Does IE8+ support it?

Comment: Like King King said you need SVG support. If u need IE8+ fallback use javascript

Comment: How can I avoid using `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`. Is there is a way to download it?

Comment: You dont need to download anything, what do u want to do?

Comment: Also, How can I use js for IE?

Comment: Just include lib in your page `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

For whatever the image you want to add gray color. Just add few lines of css like this

```
img{
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* msie */
}
```

Basically by setting the opacity for the content, it makes the content look `dull` so that it looks gray colored.

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/LGJEQ/3/)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks. But the image is still colorful. I want it to be `opacity` but also gray.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your table into a div container and then write one more div which has same height width as you table, and then you can  put that div on top of your table

```
<div class="container">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="top"></div>
```

css code

```
.container {
  position:relative;
}
.top {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
  background:#333;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
table {
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid;
}
table td {
  width:50%;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msmeL/1/) for above code